# Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String)' in my code

Tags: java

I'm doing little school project where I have to make adressbook where I can add, print contacts and I have to use Hashmap for search. This is my code and I think I have to call method get with public string in my class kontakt but I'm not quiet sure, so your help would be really appreciated.

```
 import java.util.HashMap;

 public class adresar {

    class kontakt {

        String ime;
        String broj;
        String grad;

        kontakt(String ime, String broj, String grad) {
            this.ime = ime;
            this.broj = broj;
            this.grad = grad;
        }
    }

    private HashMap<String, kontakt> osobe =
            new HashMap<String, kontakt>();

    public boolean ispisi(String ime, String broj, String grad) { //stampam kontakt iz adresara
        if (osobe.containsKey(ime)) {
            System.out.println("Osoba iz adresara je: " + ime + broj + grad);
            return false;
        } else {
            osobe.put(ime, new kontakt(ime, broj, grad)); //u slucaju da nema osobe za stampanje upisujem je
            return true;
        }
    }

    public kontakt search(String ime) { //pretrazujem po glavnom key-u, tj imenu
        return kontakt.get(ime);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, Class name starts with an UPPER CASE ><

Comment: Your class `kontakt` simply has no method `get`.

Comment: Don't you mean `osobe.get`?

Comment: You probably wanted to do `osobe.get(ime)` instead of `kontakt.get(ime)`. Your class `kontakt` does not have a `get` method.

Comment: Please obey the Java naming conventions. Class names are upper camel case (`MyClass`), variable names lower camel case (`myVariable`), methods are lower camel case (`myMethod`), constants are upper case (`MY_CONSTANT`) and packages are lower case (`mypackage`).

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't know that! From now on I will obey Java naming convention. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is undefined for class `kontakt`

```
return kontakt.get(ime);
```

should be

```
return osobe.get(ime);
```

Aside: Take a look at [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) which show that class names start with an *uppercase* character, e.g. `Kontakt`